# BayeuxServer Configuraion for Wicket Stuff Cometd?

Tags: wicket, cometd, wicketstuff

CometdPushService.get() throws NullPointerException

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicketstuff-push-cometd</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0-M5</version>
    </dependency>
```

TimerPushService.get() works as excepted but would like to use Cometd to manage bandwidth.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wicketstuff.push.cometd.CometdPushService.<init>(CometdPushService.java:133)
 at org.wicketstuff.push.cometd.CometdPushService.get(CometdPushService.java:107)
 at org.wicketstuff.push.cometd.CometdPushService.get(CometdPushService.java:97)
```

Found this good post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cometd-users/Kn13KSHqrAw however it fails at start up with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/Timeout
at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.<init>(BayeuxServerImpl.java:89)
at com.erranda.prototype.WebsocketConfiguration.bayeuxServer(WebsocketConfiguration.java:78)
at com.erranda.prototype.WebsocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e079365.CGLIB$bayeuxServer$4(<generated>)
at com.erranda.prototype.WebsocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e079365$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44de86de.invoke(<generated>)
```

Comment: Fire the debugger, Luke! Where exactly is the NPE? https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/jdk-1.7-parent/push-parent/push-cometd/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/push/cometd/CometdPushService.java#L100

Comment: Question updated martin-g.

Comment: It seems something has to set the BayuexServer: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/jdk-1.7-parent/push-parent/push-cometd/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/push/cometd/CometdPushService.java#L201

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. I use Wicket in Springboot Jetty. Is there a documentation on how setup this up.

Comment: I think you have to rephrase your question now to something like "How to setup Cometd in Spring Boot with Jetty". Also add the respective tags for springboot and jetty. Hopefully someone more experienced than us will give you the solution.